# Finding the cross points of vertical and horizontal lines (speeding up the loop)

Tags: php, loops, math

I have a series of horizontal lines and vertical lines, and I need to find all the cross points of these lines. I do this with

```
$x_lines[$x][]=array($y1,$y2); // already sorted as $y1<$y2
$y_lines[$y][]=array($x1,$x2);

foreach($x_lines as $x=>$a){
    foreach($a as $yy){
        foreach($y_lines as $y=>$b){
            foreach($b as $xx){
                if($x<$xx[0] || $x>$xx[1] || $y<$yy[0] || $y>$yy[1]){continue;}
                $crosses[]=array($x,$y);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is the performance/speed. There are thousands of lines to be tested, and we have four loops. I look for a tricky approach to find the cross points quickly.

The code is in PHP, but any solution in other programming language is sufficient. I look for the logic rather than the code.

Comment: The lines are only strictly horizontal or vertical?

Comment: The first optimization would be not to loop through EACH possible crossing line but only the possible crossing lines. As you have sorted x and y of both arrays(?)  then you only have to loop from the beginning of X-line to the X-line end in the keys of the other array. Depending on the length of lines this can massively reduce your processing time.

Comment: @AlexanderDobernig yes they are

Answer (score 1):

One simple optimization:

For any given line  FAT RED  you only need to search all crossing y-lines with the key of the parent array x

x> x_line_begin && x< x_line_end so the rosy area.

You will now get the three blue lines.

then check of the y value of the FAT RED line is in the range of each blue line.

Depending on the length of the lines proportinally to the size of the complete area it
will be a massively reduced number of calculations you have to do.

Here it will be 3/13  of a full n x n iteration.

[image: visualization]